# How to set a working directory to be used across multiple users in R, when parts of the path are different?

Tags: r

I am trying to use an R Script as a data source in a PowerBI report, that will be shared across multiple people.

However, the working directory paths for each one might be different, for example:

Mine is "C:/Users/myname/CompanyOneDriveName**/OngoingProjects/file.R**"
My coworker has "C:/Users/theirname/CompanyOneDriveName**/Documents/OngoingProjects/file.R**"

This depends on which folders we have syncronized, in my case I have only OngoingProjects, as this other person has all the folders in the Documents folder syncronized, including OngoingProjects.

Is there a way to always set the working directory to the same folder **OngoingProjects/file.R**, despite of what comes first in the path name?

I have tried:

paste0(dirname(path.expand('~')),"/OngoingProjects/file.R")

But it obviously only works if we have only the OngoingProjects folder syncronized.

Thank you to anyone who helps :)

Comment: Can you create an R project "OngoingProjects"? Then all paths can be relative from the project root folder.

Comment: See also the [`here` package](https://here.r-lib.org/)